# JSON Object from C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to acheive below JSON Object from c# code

```
{
    "Animals": {
        "name": "Animals",
        "data": [
            [
                "Cows",
                2
            ],
            [
                "Sheep",
                3
            ]
        ]
    },
    "Fruits": {
        "name": "Fruits",
        "data": [
            [
                "Apples",
                5
            ],
            [
                "Oranges",
                7
            ],
            [
                "Bananas",
                2
            ]
        ]
    },
    "Cars": {
        "name": "Cars",
        "data": [
            [
                "Toyota",
                1
            ],
            [
                "Volkswagen",
                2
            ],
            [
                "Opel",
                5
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried [json2C#](http://json2csharp.com) link and it gave me this class structure

```
public class Animals
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
}

public class Fruits
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
}

public class Cars
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Animals Animals { get; set; }
    public Fruits Fruits { get; set; }
    public Cars Cars { get; set; }
}
```

My first problem is the classes generated by code is static (Animals,Fruits,Cars) in reality it could be more and less it is category and it may be some new categories so every time I need to create a new class for each category? how can I handle this?

Second how I populate from these classes the same structure.

Please bear with me as I am very beginner level programmer.

Comment: First off, that's not valid JSON. If you're trying to achieve what you've written there, you're going to have problems. You want something more like this: http://pastebin.com/2gbQd2jb

Comment: I have updated the question, actually quotes was missin

Comment: I see that, however, it's still a very complicated schema for what you're trying to do. Moreover, since you're not defining keys for the values, they're mostly meaningless. See my pastebin example for a more appropriate format.

Comment: Thanks remus, Mr.codenoire answer has solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  Create a new console application.  You will need the JSON.NET library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Item : List<object>
    {

        public Item()
        {
            this.Add(""); // for name;
            this.Add(0); // for value;
        }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Name { get { return this[0].ToString(); } set { this[0] = value; } }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Value { get { return (int)this[1]; } set { this[1] = value; } }
    }

    class Category
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Item> data { get; set; }
        public Category()
        {
            this.data = new List<Item>();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var all = new Dictionary<string, Category>
                {
                    {
                        "Animals", new Category()
                            {
                                name = "Animals",
                                data =
                                    new List<Item>()
                                        {
                                            new Item() {Name = "Cows", Value = 2},
                                            new Item() {Name = "Sheep", Value = 3}
                                        }
                            }

                        //include your other items here
                    }
                };

            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(all));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear codenoire and Tim S., Million Thankx both of you help me alot and it  fix my problem thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separate `Animals`, `Fruits`, etc. classes. They can be merged.

```
public class Category
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
}
```

And since the list of items in the root object can change, you should use a `Dictionary<string, Category>` instead of the `RootObject` class you had generated. Your JSON is not valid, (test it with http://jsonlint.com/), but this produces something like the first part of your example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Category>
{
    { "Animals", new Category
        {
            name = "Animals",
            data = new List<List<object>>
            {
                new List<object> { "Cows", 2 },
                new List<object> { "Sheep", 3 }
            }
        }
    },
};
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
```

Produces the following (I'm using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for the serialization here). The other types would be similar. (see [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for more info on the list and dictionary initialization syntax I used, if you're unfamiliar with it; basically just shortcuts for their `Add` methods)

```
{
  "Animals": {
    "name": "Animals",
    "data": [
      [
        "Cows",
        2
      ],
      [
        "Sheep",
        3
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

If you have a choice of what the data types should be, I think it'd be better to replace the `List<object>` with a class something like this, to be more clear:

```
public class Item
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the JSON.NET library.

Then with the classes that were created:

```
string jsonStr = "{'Animals': {name: 'Animals', data: [['Cows', 2], ['Sheep', 3] ] },'Fruits': { name: 'Fruits', data: [['Apples', 5], ['Oranges', 7], ['Bananas', 2] ] }, 'Cars': {  name: 'Cars',  data: [ ['Toyota', 1], ['Volkswagen', 2],  ['Opel', 5] ] } }";

RootObject Myobj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonStr);
```